# Python Pandas: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I want to change using

```
df.loc[rowId,colId] = myDict
```

to assign a dict to the entry [rowId,colId]. As a result I get following error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Setting

```
df.loc[rowId,colId] = 0
```

works! In my pinion the style to assign the value in the first approach is the right one, so what is wrong?

Comment: kindly share actual data of ur dataframe and the dict

Comment: see below comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by adding `list`:

```
df.loc[rowId,colId] = [myDict]
```

But for better performance in pandas is best working in pandas only with scalars.

Comment: Well I'm currently working with corona dataset, that is in json. It results in one timeline per country, so the counties are the rows and a (json) timeline ist the column entry. Since there are additional columns like poulation, population density and area, it is no help to make the rows to the columns and take the times as row. I'm not sure what is a proper DataFrame structure. I ended up to SOLVE this by generating a list with dict as entries and finally assign the ENTIRE LIsT to the full column - this worked.

Comment: No, adding list does not make this possible