# ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I ran this toy code

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
test['b'] = ''
for i in range(len(test)):
    test['b'].loc[i] = [5, 6, 7]
```

I had a warning

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
```

But if I used the `loc` as per [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606746/python-pandas-valueerror-must-have-equal-len-keys-and-value-when-setting-with)

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
test['b'] = ''
for i in range(len(test)):
    test.loc[i, 'b'] = [5, 6, 7]
```

I got an error

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

What did the error mean? In particular, what keys, value and iterable it referred to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `apply`:

```
test['b'] = test['b'].apply(lambda x: [5, 6, 7])
```

or list concatenation (or list comprehension):

```
test['b'] = [[5, 6, 7]] * len(test)
```

If you have to use a loop, you could use `at` (this works because you've set `"b"` as dtype object by assigning it with `''` initially and `at` can assign values to a cell, as long as the types match):

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    test.at[i, 'b'] = [5, 6, 7]
```

Output:

```
   a          b
0  1  [5, 6, 7]
1  2  [5, 6, 7]
2  3  [5, 6, 7]
3  4  [5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks. What did you mean by *as long as the types match*? At the start I set column `b` datatype as `string` but I was still able to assign different datatype (`list` in this case). Also, what `keys`, `value` and `iterable` the error message referred to?

Comment: @Nemo pandas doesn't have string dtype, it has object dtype, so when you initialized it with a string, the column became an object dtype column, so it can be assigned anything. With `loc`, you have to assign a value that matches the length of the item you're assigning to, and since 1!=3, it throws an error. So one way to get around is: `test['b'] = [[5,6,7]] * len(test)` where the length of `test` matches the length of the list being assigned (because `[5,6,7]` is multiplied by `len(test)`)

Comment: I'm a bit slow to comprehend your answer. What `1` and `3` you referred to in this `1 != 3`? On the other hand I thought `len(test.loc[i, 'b']` is `0` so it wouldn't accept `5, 6, 7]` which had length of 3? But then you said *object dtype can be assigned anything* so I'm a bit confused :(

Comment: @Nemo my point is you cannot assign a list to `test.loc[i, 'b']`; you can only assign a single value (or a list of length 1) because it expects a singleton (whereas the list you have has length 3). By *object dtype can be assigned anything*, I meant, object dtype is like a free dtype that can include anything, lists, strings, tuples, mixed types, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because in the second snippet of code, you are trying to set values based upon the index number and not based upon the column name.

If you do:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    print(test.loc[i])
```

This gives you:

```
a    1
b     
Name: 0, dtype: object
a    2
b     
Name: 1, dtype: object
a    3
b     
Name: 2, dtype: object
a    4
b     
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

That means *using loc and i variable*, you are accessing it row wise on index and that's why you get the mismatch len error.

To overcome this warning, specifically navigate to that column using `loc`:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
test['b'] = ''
for i in range(len(test)):
    test.loc[:,'b'].loc[i] = [5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what `len` and `mismatch` to what that you referred to in this explanation *accessing it row wise on index and that's why you get the `mismatch len` error*? Also running your solution will result in SettingWithCopyWarning which I want to avoid. Thanks

Comment: So, basically, running `test.loc[i]` will give you row-wise column values. And then you want to navigate to your column value, which is not possible because it is assuming you are extracting some value, where as you want to assign some value. That is why there is `mismatch` of `key and value`

Comment: `.loc[]` -> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array. You cannot access a row and then navigate to column!. If you want to do that, you need to handle it using breaking of DataStructure type.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by *navigate to your column value, which is not possible* because I could navigate to column value with this `test.loc[i, 'b']`

Comment: But you would be able to access row-col value one at a time, and the problem doing that is, the function expects one single value to be assigned and not a bunch of list values. Since, you are assigning in one single shot, you have to do in the specified manner, or else the mismatch of lean/key-value pair will keep occuring.

Comment: Thanks. @enke explained that I could assign a `list` of length 1 to `test.loc[i, 'b']`